# XPATH syntax to select products from XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XPATH which seems to be selecting out the correct products for the category but is incorrectly selecting products when they have a qtyInStock value of 0 when in my XPath I state qtyInStock > 0.  Can anyone see what is wrong with this, I assume my syntax is incorrect.

> /products/product[category = 1234 or additionalCategories/catID =1234 
>   and qtyInStock > 0]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<product>
<prod_id>2100818</prod_id>
<productURL></productURL>
<productImageURL>jb-m-kirichigai-draw-6.jpg</productImageURL>
<category>448267</category>
<qtyInStock>2</qtyInStock>
<featured>1</featured>
<Hidden>0</Hidden>
<productName>1.5 Sun Kirichigai 6 Step with Draw Japanese Puzzle Box</productName>
<livePrice>39.4</livePrice>
<fullURL>http://www.faze3.co.uk/index.aspx?pageID=527917&amp;prodID=2100818</fullURL>
</product>
<product>
<prod_id>2101600</prod_id>
<productURL></productURL>
<productImageURL>jb-2-kiasa-7.jpg</productImageURL>
<category>448267</category>
<qtyInStock>1</qtyInStock>
<featured>1</featured>
<Hidden>0</Hidden>
<productName>2 Sun Kiasa 7 Step Japanese Puzzle Box</productName>
<livePrice>28.4</livePrice>
<fullURL>http://www.faze3.co.uk/index.aspx?pageID=527917&amp;prodID=2101600</fullURL>
</product>
<product>
<prod_id>2101795</prod_id>
<productURL></productURL>
<productImageURL>jb-2-koyosegi-7.jpg</productImageURL>
<category>448267</category>
<qtyInStock>2</qtyInStock>
<featured>1</featured>
<Hidden>0</Hidden>
<productName>2 Sun Koyosegi 7 Step Japanese Puzzle Box</productName>
<livePrice>25.95</livePrice>
<fullURL>http://www.faze3.co.uk/index.aspx?pageID=527917&amp;prodID=2101795</fullURL>
</product>
<product>
<prod_id>2102219</prod_id>
<productURL></productURL>
<productImageURL>jb-2-kuroasa-10.jpg</productImageURL>
<category>448267</category>
<qtyInStock>0</qtyInStock>
<featured>1</featured>
<Hidden>0</Hidden>
<productName>2 Sun Kuroasa 10 Step Japanese Puzzle Box</productName>
<livePrice>34.8</livePrice>
<fullURL>http://www.faze3.co.uk/index.aspx?pageID=527917&amp;prodID=2102219</fullURL>
</product>
```

Comment: Have you tried: `/products/product[(category = 1234 or additionalCategories/catID =1234) and qtyInStock > 0]`

Answer (score 1):

The `and` operator has higher precedence than the `or` operator. See [here](http://www.mulberrytech.com/papers/XPath-2-0-User-Grp-HTML/slide081.html) for details.

Instead try the below (note the grouping with brackets)

`/products/product[(category = 1234 or additionalCategories/catID =1234) and qtyInStock > 0]`